# Calling function with call in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call a function from outside a class, and I want this function to have access to the same `this` variable (which means to props, refs, etc). I've been trying:

```
const something = (() => {
    console.log(this); // undefined
});

class FooBar extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {something.call(this)}
            </div>
        );
    };

};
```

However, using `Function.prototype.call`, `this` is still undefined. Same thing happens with `apply`, and bind doesn't execute a function immediately. What's wrong?

Comment: Could you try this : `const something = function() { console.log(this); }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to, sir :

```
const something = function() {  
    console.log(this); // FooBar
};
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/enfer/pen/qqejaV

Comment: Yup, works this way - but why it's not working as an arrow function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
Section "Invoked through call or apply" :)